# How to import a keyboard command function in a python programme?

Tags: python, import

I want to make a programme which takes a input when I press a keyboard key. Say if I press the key (P) on keyboard, I want to instead act is as the key (Q) and relay that command to the system. I'm a complete newbie, so any tips are always welcome.

I tried the the .import function but can't get a grasp of it after watching multiple videos on different platforms.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the input command. As long as the computer you're using has python downloaded, all native functionality will be included, including the "input" command.
I'm not sure of the exact functionality you're looking for but you can compare the input to say 'p' for example and change it to 'q'

```
print('What is your name?') # Prints to the terminal
name = input() # Waits for computer input, say you enter a P
if(name == 'p'):
    name = 'q'
print('hello, ' + name) # Prints out "hello your_name", unless the input was a p, then it would output "hello q"
```

Check out W3: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_input.asp

Comment: Hey, What I want to do is to make a standalone exe programme which I can run on X86, I alr know about the input command and I'm not sure if it would work for standalone. And while we are at can you tell me how I would convert that (P) keyboard input to (Q), I suppose it would be rather simple but I lack the knowledge. I now the basic keywords and their functions, but arranging them in a meaningful syntax is difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Python has a keyboard module with many features. Install it, perhaps with this command:

```
pip install keyboard
```

you can detect keyboard presses by this code.

```
import keyboard
while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('a'):
        print('a is pressed')
        break
```

I think you want something similar to this code:

```
import keyboard
while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
        keyboard.press('p')
        print('P is pressed')
        break
```

Comment: Hey I tried it and it works fine but it has 3 flaws. 1) It doesn't loop, ideally we want it to loop but i can manage that myself. 2) When executed as standalone it types both the letters p and q. 3) The executable standalone is killed after 1 use.